# Running codeigniter 3 cron job issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm trying to run a codeigniter 3 cron job. If I open the file manually it works through the browser and I find databse updated and emails are sent

```
https://www.example.com/module_name/controller/method
```

But not working through a cron job like this *every minute on a private server*

```
curl --silent https://www.example.com/module_name/controller/method
```

Also tried

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php module_name controller method
```

Any idea or other ways to run it?

Comment: open a command line window on the server, and run the job, as if you were cron.  Then if there are errors you will more then probably see them.  PHP can sometimes use a different `ini` config for the `cli (command line interface)` so you could have any number of environmental issues.  Personally I would avoid using `curl` if possible.  But that depends, `curl` should run it using the normal `ini` just like a `browser`.  I prefer not using `curl` because of that, and other things.

Comment: you shouldn't need all this `/usr/local/bin/php` on `linux`, or at least most servers I seen have it setup already, where you can just do `php {path to file}`

Comment: Not asking about other ways actually but asking for a working method because what I used doesn't work I'll try to test and reply. Thank you

Comment: I wasn't telling you about `other ways`.  The problem with cron, is it happens in the dark, you can't see the script output, correct.  So, if you manually run it on the command line, with the same command cron uses. Then you bring it into the light...  For example if you run it on the command line and it says, `class Pdo not found` then you would know that the `php-cli.ini` file does not have `pdo` enabled. etc...  There is probably a billion reasons why it wouldn't work.  And saying it's not working dosn't really narrow that down any.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first go to a terminal and check that your php is actually at /usr/local/bin/php by running:

```
which php
```

You mentioned that you'd like to know other ways to run the cron, and I've used wget many times. For you that would look something like:

```
/usr/bin/wget https://www.example.com/module_name/controller/method -O /dev/null
```

In most(all?) Linux distros, you're going to open crontab for editing using:

```
crontab -e
```

Once in there, just add a line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget https://www.example.com/module_name/controller/method -O /dev/null
```

Do ensure that you have wget available, and it's location by running:

```
which wget
```

Comment: what's `-O /dev/null`  I use `>/dev/null 2>&1` all the time.  Used to be CentOs 5 would crash cron after about 2MB of output ( if I recall maybe it was 2G ), I don't use wget, so is that like the equivalent. Basically throw away the output?

Comment: Yes, for wget you need the -O parameter. Look up the man page for wget to see the details. `>/dev/null 2>&1` will still output when using wget. I know it's weird, but it's happened to me before, and that's how I know.

Comment: `Kool`, Like I said I never run command line stuff with `wget` I just use `php`.  I was just curious.

Comment: I don't like to run crons using wget, but I've had to use crons in hosting environments that were so screwed up that wget worked when nothing else did.